# How to update single value in map without updating all map in firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

it is possible to update single value in map in document in Firestore without updating entire map in Flutter?

Example: I have doc with some map like on screen below. Is it possible to update a single value e.g. I want to change 2 to 'abc' without updating the entire map in Flutter?

[image]

Comment: If it's a map, you can update an individual element by addressing it as `players.2`. If it's an array, there is no way to change individual items based on their index.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update a nested map property, use dot notation to give a path to the property to update:

```
documentReference.update({ "players.1": "value" })
```